# same function in R, but used in function gives other result than used in script with the same parameters

Tags: r

I am finding a parameter theta which used in lprim is almost zero, then my function stops and returns it, but outside of it it gives 44.55. I have no idea where should I look for a bug.

```
set.seed(0)

lprim <- function(X, theta, sigma) {
  n = length(X)
  return((1 / sigma) * (n - 2 * sum(exp(-(X - theta) / sigma) / (1 + exp(-(X - theta)/sigma)))))
}
lbis = function(X, theta, sigma){
  return(-2 / sigma ^ 2 * sum( exp(-(X - theta) / sigma) / (1 + exp(-(X - theta)/sigma))^2))
}

X = rlogis(50, 1, 1)
Newton = function(start, koniec, X, sigma) {
  i = 0
  theta = start
  while (abs(lprim(X, theta, sigma)) > 0.000001 & i < 5000){
    a = lprim(X, theta, sigma)
    b = lbis(X, theta, sigma)
    theta = theta - a / b
    i = i + 1
  }
  x = abs(lprim(X, theta, sigma))
  return(c(theta, sigma))
}
debug(lprim)
z = Newton(1, 5000, X, 1)
abs(lprim(X, z[0], z[1]))
```

Comment: Oh, sorry it is there, I deleted one unused function copying and it looks that also a curly closing bracket

Comment: I just ran the code with the seed set and got the result `[1] 41.32998`. Unsure if this is what you wanted it to be? Would you be able to explain what you're expecting to happen

Comment: should remove the picture since it contains a different seed.

Comment: @Mark I think OP is wondering why the `x` inside the function has a different value than the last line of code

Comment: yes, what @Derf said is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming what you mean by *almost zero* is the value of `x` inside `Newton`.

The referencing in the last part is wrong. Indexing in R starts at 1. `theta` is actually at `z[1]`. Overall your last line should be,

```
abs(lprim(X, z[1], z[2]))
```